# Non-greedy matching in sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

In a bash script, I have the following variable:

```
file_name='this_is_the_hart_part.csv'
```

Using

```
var2=$(echo $file_name | sed -e 's/_{2}\(.*\)_{3}/\1/')
```

I want to extract the substring "the" (between underscores number 2 and 3 in variable $file_name).

But I get back $var2 equal to $file_name. How do I have to change my sed command?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kusalananda is right that `sed` is the wrong tool and you cannot do non-greedy matching. But you can use a workaround for non-greedy matching: 
`[^_]*` will match any character that is not `_`

So in your case you could do something like this:

```
printf '%s\n' "$file_name" | sed -e 's/^[^_]*_[^_]*_\([^_]*\).*$/\1/g'
```

But ... for your use case, you should better use other tools ...

Comment: You still need to use `printf '%s\n' "$file_name"` to be sure that the filename is not split by the shell or filename globbed, or get backslashes messed up. At least double quote the expansion...  See e.g. [Stéphane's answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/496428/116858)

Answer (score 5):

The types of regular expressions supported by `sed` does not allow for non-greedy matching with `*`.

You want to get the 3rd `_`-delimited field. This is easiest done with `cut`:

```
cut -d '_' -f 3
```

Or, with `awk`:

```
awk -F '_' '{ print $3 }'
```

Or, in the shell, by removing the first two such fields in succession, and then trimming the end:

```
str=${file_name#*_}
str=${str#*_}
str=${str%%_*}
```

`"$str"` would be the word `the` at the end.  Using this last variation would likely be the fastest and most robust way out of these three.

The variable substitution `${variable#*_}` would result in a string that is `$variable` with the leading bit up to and including the first underscore removed.  The `${variable%%_*}` would remove everything from the first underscore to the end of `$variable`.  These are standard variable substitutions.

The benefit of using the variable substitution on a filename is that it would cope with filenames containing newlines, which neither `awk` nor `sed` or `cut` would do.  In general, don't use line-oriented text editing tools on filenames.

In addition, you are using `echo $file_name`.  Since `$file_name` is unquoted, it would undergo word-slitting (on every character that is also part of `$IFS`; a space, tab and newline by default) and the generated words, if they contain filename globbing characters, would be matched against filenames in the current directory by the shell. And backslashes in the filename may also disappear or have unwanted effects (even if you quote the expansion).  The `ksh` shell would also do brace expansions on the value of `$file_name` when it's unquoted.

Comment: Note that it's not _every whitespace or characters of $IFS_, it's _characters of $IFS_ only (and IFS by default contains space, TAB and NL which is not *every* whitespace). (Also note that ksh also does brace expansion upon variable expansion).

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Thanks for being pedantic :-) I'll fix it up.

Answer (score 3):

First note that `sed` is a *text* utility that works by default on one line at at a time while filenames can contain any character (including newline) and even non-characters (can be non-*text*).

Also, [leaving a variable unquoted has a very special meaning](/q/68694), you almost never want to do that, it's also [potentially very dangerous](/q/171346).

Also, [you can't use `echo` to output arbitrary data, use `printf` instead](/q/65803).

Also, variable assignment syntax in Bourne-like shells is: `var=value`, not `$var=value`.

You can load the whole output of `echo` (or better, `printf`) into `sed`'s pattern space with:

```
printf '%s\n' "$filename" | sed -e :1 -e '$!{N;b1' -e '}'
```

Then, you can add the code to extract the part between the second and third `_`:

```
var2=$(
  printf '%s\n' "$filename" |
   sed -ne :1 -e '$!{N;b1' -e '}' -e 's/^\([^_]*_\)\{2\}\([^_]*\)_.*/\2/p'
)
```

The non-greedy part is addressed by using `[^_]*` (a sequence of non-`_` characters) which, contrary to `.*` guarantees we don't match past `_` boundaries (though it would still choke on non-characters in many implementations).

In this case here, you could use shell parameter expansion operators instead:

```
case $filename in
  (*_*_*_*) var2=${filename#*_*_}; var2=${var2%%_*};;
  (*)       var2=;;
esac
```

Which would work better if the filename is not text or if the part you want to extract ends in a newline character (and would also be more efficient).

Some shells like `zsh` or `ksh93` have more advanced operators:

- `zsh`:

  split on `_` and get third field:

  ```
  var2=${"${(@s:_:)filename}"[3]}
  ```

  Using the `${var/pattern/replacement}` and back-references (in that case, you want to verify first that the variable contains at least 3 underscores or there won't be any substitution).

  ```
  set -o extendedglob
  var2=${filename/(#b)*_*_(*)_*/$match[1]}
  ```
- `ksh93`:

  ```
  var2=${filename/*_*_@(*)_*/\1}
  ```

Comment: Why not use a here string to load the filename into sed? Like `sed -e ... <<<"$filename"`

Comment: You can as well, but that doesn't bring any advantage over `printf ... | sed` and is less portable (`<<<` is a zsh feature, which has not been copied by all other shells yet; whether `bash` will use a tempfile or a pipe for it depends on the version and the size of the data being fed)